# Getting text node using Mechanize?

Tags: ruby, xpath, web, nokogiri, mechanize

Using [Mechanize](http://mechanize.rubyforge.org/) I want to get the text node following an HTML element:

```
<b>test</b>THIS IS THE TEXT I WANT.
```

How do I get that text once I have the `<b>` node using `page.at('b')`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That would be:

```
page.at('b').next
```

Comment: I thought that this grabbed html nodes only?

Comment: @babonk, the text is a node. For the next element you might do: `page.at('b').at('+ *')`